# File explorer doesnt show preview for Word, Excel, pptx, and txt files, but it shows preview for pdf, jpg and odt files

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, preview

File explorer doesnt show preview for Word, Excel, pptx, and txt files. It shows preview for pdf, jpg and odt files. Says "preview not available". When I used ShellExView v2.01, I saw that CLSID: {84F66100-FF7C-4fb4-B0C0-02CD7FB668FE} is linked with File extension .odt, and not .doc or .docx, as I expected for Microsoft Word previewer. ShellExView v2.01 does not let me edit this property back to .docx. Similarly Excel previewer is associated with .ods and PowerPoint previewer with .odp. Is this the reason why I cant preview these files? If so how can I reset the previewers? I tried editing registery but it only says that {84F66100-FF7C-4fb4-B0C0-02CD7FB668FE} is associated with Mocrosoft Word, and does not show any extensions. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems  you've installed LibreOffice, and then removed it,

- Either update (i.e., reinstall) LibreOffice, and set it as the default for opening Word, PowerPoint and other MS Office files, an option in the installation,
- Or in Windows *Settings > Choose default apps by file type*, set LibreOffice (or MS Office) as the default. (Yes, it slow to have to set *each* extension.)

[image: Default Apps]

- Or reinstall Microsoft Office.